# MPAndroidChart limit line color not quite correct

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

MPAndroidCharts is so great.

I've changed my LineChart Limit line (and Text) color to an accent color used all over my app.  However, the color of the line (and text) is much darker when compared to the rest.  I suspect this is because the color is mixing with the chart background color have set - not sure though

What I've tried so far.

1)  Set the drawable in the xml and programmatically.  No change.

2)  setDrawLimitLinesBehindData(false);  No change.

3) changing the background color to a different shade.  No apparent change.

Answer (score 1):

The color you want to apply, add that in your colors.xml. After that add following line:

```
ll.setLineColor(getContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.your_color));
```